# Не удается подключится к SQL серверу python, pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

Пытаюсь подключится к sql серверу, но получаю следующую ошибку:

```py
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '193.109.79.82' ([WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение)")
```

При этом порт вроде бы прослушивается на сервере, как я понял:

Скриншот:
[image: s]

Вот код:

```py
con = pymysql.connect(db='db', user='user', passwd='passwd', host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
```

Comment: ваше приложение на том же сервере?

Comment: что реально в `host=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ответу, Вы пытаетесь подключиться к mysql с другого компьютера (сервера), и если Вы не настраивали изначально mysql сервер, то подключиться к нему из-вне не получится, поскольку, по умолчанию, в mysql сервере порт наружу не смотрит (секьюрити как никак).
На сервре, в my.cnf нужно найти строку типа

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

и заменить на

```
bind-address = xxx.yyy.zzz.vvv
```

Где xxx.yyy.zzz.vvv = 0.0.0.0 (подключение  будет доступно для всех),
либо xxx.yyy.zzz.vvv = IP сервера (или компьютера) с вашим приложением/скриптом.

Answer (score 0):

На картинке видно, что база слушает на `127.0.0.1`.

Если приложение находится на том же хосте -- проверьте адрес/порт в `connect`.

Если на другом -- значит оно до чужого `127.0.0.1` не достанет, и надо:

- или пробросить порт
- или настроить базу, чтоб слушала на видимом приложению IP (не забыв про безопасность базы)